# Custom webpart on home page of MOSS 2007 site

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How to manipulate the permissions of custom webparts ? I want to make the custom webpart visible to few other users on the home page. But I don't find edit (Modify shared webpart) like OOB webpart where the permission can be controlled using 'Target Audiences'.

I have searched in webparts gallery, I did not find the webpart at all because I clicked and checked preview of all the webparts in the gallery.

can you please help how to find 'what is that custom webpart in the home page ?'  ?

This custom webpart shows few hyperlinks, that's all.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure it actually is a Web Part and not just part of the page or master page?